# Songs not getting played by setQueueWithItemCollection api

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I am testing the following simple code on my iphone 4 with iOS 5.0 on it. I implemented the following sample code to play a user selected song. The user clicks on the a button on the page, its shows his playlist/songs .... but once the song is selected and picker is dismissed, the song doesnt play. What gives?

From my *.h file

```
@interface MusicPlayerDemoViewController : UIViewController <MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate> {
    MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;



- (IBAction)selectMusic:(id)sender;
```

from my *.m file

```
- (IBAction)selectMusic:(id)sender 
{
    MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO; // this is the default   
    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES];
    [mediaPicker release];
}                                   

// Media picker delegate methods
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {

// We need to dismiss the picker
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


  [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:mediaItemCollection];
  [musicPlayer play];
}

- (void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

SOLUTION:

Add the following code in ViewDidLoad. I wasn't instantiating the player. All works

```
[self setMusicPlayer: [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]];

    // By default, an application music player takes on the shuffle and repeat modes
    //      of the built-in iPod app. Here they are both turned off.
    [musicPlayer setShuffleMode: MPMusicShuffleModeOff];
    [musicPlayer setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeNone];
```

Comment: I am doing a @synthesize musicPlayer; incase you are wondering. Code Compile is not the problem here.

Comment: Where do you instantiate the musicPlayer?

Comment: What are you saying, I don't understand

Comment: thank you jamingug for pointing me in the right direction.